# NSFetchedResultsController only sorting by 1st sort descriptor

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm seeing an issue where the NSFetchedResultsController is only sorting by the first `NSSortDescriptor` in the `sortDescriptors` array when the data changes.  It's really infuriating.

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController to manage a tableview that is displaying a list of items.  These items have an inherent order based on the `number` property, but a user can favorite an item.  Favorited items are displayed at the top of the table view, sorted by the `number` property.

So, the model looks something like this:

```m
@interface Thing : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *number;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *favorite;
@end

@implementation Thing
    @dynamic number;
    @dynamic favorite;
@end
```

And I'm configuring my `NSFetchedResultsController` like so:

```m
- (void)loadView {
    ...
    //
    // configure fetched results controller for the things table view
    NSFetchRequest *fetchThings = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchChannels.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Thing class]) 
                                       inManagedObjectContext:[DataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];
    fetchThings.sortDescriptors = @[
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"favorite" ascending:NO],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES] ];
    
    _fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchThings
                                                           managedObjectContext:[DataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                      cacheName:nil];
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error performing fetch! %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

When the table is initially loaded, `_fetchController` correctly sorts the items, so you could end up with something like this:

```m
- Thing: favorite = YES, number = 2
- Thing: favorite = YES, number = 3
- Thing: favorite = NO, number = 1
- Thing: favorite = NO, number = 4
```

But if you were to un-favorite Thing Number 2, it only sorts by the 1st sort descriptor, and the list looks like this:

```m
- Thing: favorite = YES, number = 3
- Thing: favorite = NO, number = 2
- Thing: favorite = NO, number = 1
- Thing: favorite = NO, number = 4
```

Has anyone run into this issue or found a work around for it?

### Update

It would appear that if I favorite *everything*, then unfavorite *everything*, the sorting works itself out.  This leads me to believe this could be a faulting issue?  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to work around that, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, and it's my own fault.

Just because the field represents a `BOOL` doesn't mean it's actually a `BOOL`.  The `favorite` field in the `Thing` model is actually an `NSNumber`, and as such, has **3** states, `@(YES)`, `@(NO)`, and `nil`.  Once I made sure I was initializing the `favorite` field properly the sorting started working as expected again.

Comment: You absolutelly right. I had same issue with sorting, and also figured, that bool value in NSNumber can have 3 state YES, NO, and nil.